# Sum and intersection of sets

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $U:=5\mathbb{Z}$, $V:=(-6)\mathbb{Z}$, $W:=9\mathbb{Z}$.

So we have the sets \begin{align*}&U=5\mathbb{Z}=\{5x \mid x\in \mathbb{Z}\} \\ &V=(-6)\mathbb{Z}=\{-6x \mid x\in \mathbb{Z}\} \\ &W=9\mathbb{Z}=\{9x \mid x\in \mathbb{Z}\}\end{align*}

I want to give natural numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $U+V=a\mathbb{Z}$, $U\cap V=b\mathbb{Z}$, $V+W=c\mathbb{Z}$, $V\cap W=d\mathbb{Z}$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

It holds that $U+V=\{u+v\mid u\in U \text{ and } v\in V\}$.

From the definition of the sets $u$ is of the form $5x$ and $v$ of the form $-6y$.

So the set $U+V$ elements of the form $5x-6y$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $U+V=a\mathbb{Z}$, we have that an element is of form $az$.

So we have that $az=5x-6y$.

Have can we find $a$ ?

For the intersection, an element must be in the form $5x$ and $-6y$. So since $U\cap V=b\mathbb{Z}$ we have an element of the form $bz$ which is of the form $5x$ and $-6y$. So must $b$ be a multile of $5$ and of $-6$ ?

Comment: Is it not simpler to try to solve this using ideals?

Answer (score 1):

For the set sums, you'll want to reference [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

Let us be given $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(a,b) = d$. Then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=d$.

For example, in the $U+V$ case, you'll have $5x+6y=1$ since $5,6$ are coprime.

(I abandon the negative in the $6$ here for simplicity; it can be argued to be absorbed into the $y$ since it's an integer and thus $-y$ is one too, if you like, or you can do the same work with the negative.)

You can thus show you can write any $k \in \Bbb Z$ by multiplying through by $k$, as $(5k)x + (6k)y = k$, and $5k,6k$ are in $U,V$ respectively. So by the existence of the $x,y$ and the presence of the $5k,6k$ in their sets, $U+V = \Bbb Z$.

Or, phrased differently for clarity: say you want to write some $k \in \Bbb Z$ in terms of elements from $U$ and $V$. You get the $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ that are guaranteed from Bézout's identity. Then $k=5kx+6ky$. $5kx$ is in $U$ since it's an integer multiple of $5$, and similar for $6ky$ being in $V$.

Similarly, for $V+W$, you can conclude the sum is $3 \Bbb Z$.

More generally, if $A = a \Bbb Z$ and $B = b \Bbb Z$, then by the preceding logic, $A+B = \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z$.

---

For the intersections, you have the right idea, but it doesn't generalize too nicely to other sets since you by happenstance have that $5,6$ are coprime. For example, your idea wouldn't work for $V \cap W$ as it would skip some valid members like $18$.

More generally, let us have $A = a\Bbb Z, B = b \Bbb Z$. What is $A \cap B$? Clearly, to be in both sets, an element can have the form $abk$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, but this is not quite sufficient. For example, with $a=4,b=16$, this would imply only elements of the form $64k$ are in the set, but what about the obvious $16$ or $32$?

Instead consider elements of the form $\text{lcm}(a,b)\cdot k$, i.e. integer multiples of their least common multiple. Since $a,b$ both divide their least common multiple by definition, it follows that elements of this form are in the intersection. In fact, it is precisely all elements of that form that are common to both sets.

And thus, $A \cap B = (a \Bbb Z) \cap (b \Bbb Z) = \text{lcm}(a,b) \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Can we show that $U+V=1\mathbb{Z}$ only using the gcd?